# -ed and -ing adjective, how to use it properly?

Tags: adjectives

Why is it grammatically correct to use these -ing adjectives:

- annoying habit
- exciting news

and NOT these -ed adjectives:

- annoyed habit
- excited news

Comment: Think it through - how often have you seen the news ever get excited, or a habit get annoyed?

Comment: @Tetsujin I know that habits annoyed me, and news excited me. So presumably that's excited news and annoyed habits? I.e. it's not that simple, imo ;-)

Comment: nope, that's you excited &/or annoyed. The news & the habits never worried about it at all.

Comment: I know what it is old bean, (I'm a native speaker!). My point is that in many languages these ING and ED adjectives are just 1 adjective. So the for example, the words *boring* and *bored* are the same word in Spanish. It's difficult for some learners, therefore, to learn the difference ... :) They can't really just 'think it through' - it's too confusing

Answer (score 7):

**Agents and patients**

In the sentence:

- Bob punched me.

Bob is the person doing the action. In grammar, we say that Bob is the *AGENT* of the punching action. Me, the person receiving the punches, I'm the *PATIENT*. I am the recipient of the punching action. Now look at this sentence:

- I was punched by Bob.

The grammar of this sentence is different, but Bob is still the agent, and I am still the patient of this sentence. Bob is doing the action. The action is being done *to* me.

**Adjectives**

Now, some adjectives explain how nouns *do things*, sometimes to other people or things. Here are some examples:

- The DJ played *annoying music* all night.
- The elephant told us an *interesting story*.
- Rain supplies *life-giving water* to the plants in the forest.

Notice that in these examples the music has the effect of annoying people. The story has the property of interesting people. The water has the property of giving life to other things. These *-ING* adjectives describe potential actions:

- annoying, interesting, giving life

The nouns that these adjectives describe, are the potential *AGENTS* of the actions. In the phrase

- annoying music

.. the word *music* describes the agent of the *annoying* action. *ING*-adjectives usually describe the AGENTS of the potential action.

However, adjectives ending in *-ED* are different! This is because *ED*-adjectives describe the *PATIENTS* of actions.

- The *bored students* went to sleep.
- The *excited monkeys* started howling.
- Happy customers are easier to talk to than *annoyed customers*

In the sentences above, the students didn't bore anybody. Something or somebody bored *them*. They were the recipients of a *boring people* action. Similarly, something excited the monkeys. The monkeys didn't excite anybody. In the last sentence, something annoyed the customers. They did not annoy somebody else.

**The Original Posters Question**

> - annoying habit
> - exciting news
> - *annoyed habit (wrong)
> - *excited news (wrong)

*ING* adjectives describe the AGENTS of actions. But *ED* describe the *PATIENTS* of actions.  *Annoyed habit* is wrong, because nothing annoyed the habit! Habits don't have feelings, so it is very difficult to annoy habits! In the same way, "news" doesn't have feelings. We can't excite the news! Of course the news can excite people and habits can annoy people. For this reason, *exciting news* and *annoying habits* are perfectly correct.

**This is *frightenING***:

[image]

**This is *frightenED***

[image]

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: Excellent answer! And I love the pic for frightened!