# What's the difference between 'time-consuming' and 'time-consumed'?

Tags: adjectives, hyphens

How do I distinguish whether to use `v-ing` or `v-ed` within compound adjective?

Comment: _time-consumed_ doesn't exist as an established word. Its obvious meaning would be "consumed by time", which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Colin Fine Yeah, it seems that I get the point

Answer (score 2):

To describe any event that takes a lot of time, we use the adjective "time-consuming", not "time-consumed".

From the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/time-consuming),

> A time-consuming task takes a lot of time to do:
> *Producing a dictionary is a very time-consuming job.*

"time consumed" is not an adjective and it takes on the meaning of "duration", i.e. the amount of time taken for an event.

> 1. While the average length of meetings declined, the total time consumed by meetings increased substantially.
> 2. To begin with, the time consumed in virtual meetings exploded.

Comment: But, what is the general rule of using ing or ed?

Comment: @yixuan For the usage of `-ing` and `-ed` in general, you can check out this answer. [-ed and -ing adjective, how to use it properly?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49796/ed-and-ing-adjective-how-to-use-it-properly)

Comment: The task consumes your time, it doesn't have its time consumed.

Comment: @KateBunting Right, I can find scattered [examples of such usage online](https://hbr.org/2020/12/the-pandemic-is-widening-a-corporate-productivity-gap) - "While the average length of meetings declined, the total time consumed by meetings increased substantially." However, I agree it's an awkward way of saying it. Will update my answer, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @user86610 My understanding is, for example: "time-consuming task", task is agent and time is patient, task will consume time, time is instead consumed. According to grammar, the phrase "time-consumed" seems to be more correct, although I am aware of that it's wrong.

Comment: @user86610 I wasn't commenting on your answer, I was trying to indicate the difference. To use another verb as an example: An _all-seeing_ eye can see everything, but a _seldom-seen_ thing is not often seen by people.

Comment: @KateBunting Oops, my apologies for the confusion. Thanks for your clarification too.